# Proper way to use Try Catch for different situations in C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm working with the following code, but I'm not sure how is the proper way to do it.

```
try
{
      // Do code for Try1 
      Console.WriteLine("Try1 Successful");             
}

try
{
      // If try1 didn't work. Do code for Try2
      Console.WriteLine("Try2 Successful");    
}

try
{
      // If try2 didn't work. Do code for Try3
      Console.WriteLine("Try3 Successful");             
}

catch (Exception)
{
      // If try1, 2 and 3 didn't work. print this:
      Console.WriteLine("The program failed");        
}
```

What I want is to try 3 different ways of a task, and if the 3 of them fail, print "The program failed", but if one of them is successful, don't do the other ones and continue with the program

Edit:

The task that I am trying to do, is looking for a NETWORK PATH.

The Task 1 will look if a path can be opened, if so OPEN THE DIRECTORY.

If not: Task 2 will look if a second path can be opened, if so OPEN THE DIRECTORY.

If not: Task 3 will look if a third path works, if so OPEN IT.

If not "no paths can be found on this pc"

Comment: That sounds like you'd want the second try in the first catch, then the thrid try in the second catch, and the final catch would print failed. like this `try { firstThing; } catch { try { secondThing;} catch{ try { thirdThing; } catch { printFailure; } } }`

Comment: If there are ways in which you know at design time that your try1, try2, try3 etc code can fail, you should try to write them in a way which indicates to the caller that they didn't work. Return a boolean to indicate success or failure, or implement your own specific Exception type, throw that exception type from your try1 etc code, and catch just that exception type. `catch(Exception)` will catch (almost) all exception types, and should only be used in limited circumstances, mainly at the top level of your application to log what went wrong rather than crashing the application completely

Comment: If you can edit your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what your try1, try2 etc code is doing, we could help you to improve your error handling.

Comment: This looks like a very bad design. I can't remember ever having to write or to read such code. If you are in full control of the called code, design it in a way that there are no exceptions throw. If you have no access to the source code, then check the the pre-conditions before executing the critical code. In your case use e.g. Directory.Exists or File.Exists to check if a directory/file exists. Your rendered scenario can simply avoid any exception. Exceptions are really expensive and can drastically slow down your application.

Comment: @BinonicCode I totally agree, design for no exceptions unless it's completely out of your control whether or not they happen. Funnily enough, if I had enough information to post a proper answer, I'd also use IOException in file/directory does/doesn't exist/is locked by another process scenarios to illustrate how to do things :-)

Comment: @sbridewell Due to the lack of information I voted to close the answer already. It's impossible to answer such a broad question. You have to know the actual code. There is never a single solution that's best for all cases. The best solution can differ from case to case.

Comment: @BionicCode everything you say about what is wrong with this question is true, I just want to give a new contributor a chance to learn and edit their question accordingly.

Comment: @JorgeRangel I see you've edited the question (thank you) and now you seem to have a single "open the directory" operation, which you want to call multiple times but for a different directory each time? Could you share the code of the method where you've implemented this "open the directory" functionality? This could simplify the question and the answer significantly

Comment: @sbridewell, thanks a lot for your help, please see for my solution in this post. The tasks that I am trying are to see if a folder in a network path is found. And the reason that I have try-catch is that no everyone has the same access to those paths. So what I am doing is to check for each path, and if the first works, open it and that's it.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeRangel, that's the missing detail we need, although a better place for it would be in an edit to your question, rather than an answer. The key point for me is that you not only want to handle the possibility that a folder doesn't exist, but also the possibility that the current user doesn't have access to it. There are cleaner ways of doing this, without catching `System.Exception`. I'll post a complete answer later today if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it without try catch block.
For the simplicity make that Task1, Task2, Task3, have some kind of return types.
For example if they return boolean type. TRUE if Task succededd or FALSE if Task failed.

Or they can return some custom type with boolean result, and string error message. I would not go with nested try catch blocks.

```
executeTasks() {

  Console.WriteLine("Try 1");
  if (Task1()) return;

  Console.WriteLine("Try 2");
  if (Task2()) return;

  Console.WriteLine("Try 3");
  if (Task3()) return;

  Console.WriteLine("The program failed");

}
```

Comment: That top level flow looks much better. But keep in mind that each Task# method could internally catch an exception and retun a bool from inside the catch block. This would still introduce the exception perfomance penalty. You should make sure that each Task# method is implemented to avoid throwing exceptions by validating the pre-conditions for the critical method call. In this case the method could use Directory.Exists("the_path") and only execute critical code if the checking succeeds. Calling critical code and catch the exception to test if the provided path is not valid is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this snippet can be easily adapted to meet your needs.

```
namespace StackOverflow69019117TryCatch
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void MainMethod()
        {
            var paths = new string[] {
                @"C:\Users\otherUser\Documents", // exists but I don't have access to it
                @"C:\temp", // exists but doesn't contain the folderToSearchFor subfolder
                @"Z:\doesntexist", // doesn't exist
            };

            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Trying with path {path}");
                if (this.ProcessDirectory(path, "folderToSearchFor"))
                {
                    // We've succeeded so exit the loop
                    Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded using path {path}");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // We've failed so continue round the loop and hope we succeed next time
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed using path {path}");
                }
            }
        }

        private bool ProcessDirectory(string directoryPath, string folderToSearchFor)
        {
            // First, check whether the directory we want to search actually exists.
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                // Then the directory we're trying to search in doesn't exist.
                // Return false, no need to incur the overhead of an exception.
                Console.WriteLine($"Directory {directoryPath} doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }

            // This doesn't appear to throw an exception if directoryPath isn't accessible to the current user.
            // Instead it just returns whatever the current user has access to (which may be an empty array).
            var propFolderCandidates = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath, $"{folderToSearchFor}*");

            // But did it return anything?
            // If not then what we're looking for either doesn't exist or the user doesn't have access to it.
            if (propFolderCandidates.Length == 0)
            {
                // Then there's no folder here matching the search path.
                // Return false, no need to incur the overhead of an exception.
                Console.WriteLine($"Couldn't find folder matching {folderToSearchFor} in {directoryPath}");
                return false;
            }

            var propFolder = propFolderCandidates[0];

            // Consider implementng similar checks in Process.Start.
            // e.g. if it's reading a file, check whether the file exists first
            if (Process.Start(propFolder))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Process.Start succeeded using {directoryPath}");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Process.Start failed using {directoryPath}");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As @BionicCode has pointed out in various comments, it's less expensive to check whether an action might throw an exception before performing that action, than it is to perform the action and then handle the exception if it's thrown by the action.

I had to do a bit of digging to establish what happens when `Directory.GetDirectories` tries to get the subfolders of a folder that the current user doesn't have access to - I was expecting it to throw an exception, but it seems that it doesn't, it just returns an empty array representing the nothing that the current user has access to in that location, so no exception to handle in that scenario.

Throwing and catching of exceptions definitely has its place in .net software, but you should treat it as something to fall back on if something happens which you can't anticipate at design time - if there's a way at design time of detecting that a particular action isn't going to work, then you should detect it and report to the caller that the action they've requested won't work, rather than performing the action and trying to handle any exception it might throw.

There is some wise advice from Microsoft on the subject of [best practice for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions).

> Use exception handling if the event doesn't occur very often, that is, if the event is truly exceptional and indicates an error (such as an unexpected end-of-file). When you use exception handling, less code is executed in normal conditions.

> Check for error conditions in code if the event happens routinely and could be considered part of normal execution. When you check for common error conditions, less code is executed because you avoid exceptions.

Hope this is useful :-)

Answer (score -2):

You're gonna have to nest your try-catch blocks:

```
try {
    Console.WriteLine("Try1 successful");
} catch {
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("Try2 successful");
    } catch {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Try3 successful");
        } catch {
            Console.WriteLine("The program failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have already found a way, to be honest I don't know if this is the best way, but totally works.

The solution was to nest a few try-catch(exception)

This is what I am doing...

```
try
{
    try
    {
        //Check if PROP  can be found inside initial path A
        string[] PROP_FOLDER = Directory.GetDirectories(Full_PathA, $"{PROP}*");

        Process.Start(PROP_FOLDER[0]);

        //Open PROP in path A and RETURN
        status_label.Text = "  Found it!";
        status_label.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
    }
    catch (Exception)   //If an error occurs on path A
    {
        try
        {            
            //Check if PROP  can be found inside initial path B
            string[] PROP_FOLDER = Directory.GetDirectories(Full_PathB, $"{PROP}*");

            Process.Start(PROP_FOLDER[0]);
            //Open PROP in path B and RETURN
            status_label.Text = "  Found it!";
            status_label.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;    
        }
        catch (Exception) //If an error occurs on path B
        {
            
            //Check if PROP can be found inside initial path C                     
            string[] PROP_FOLDER = Directory.GetDirectories(Full_PathC, $"{PROP}*");

            Process.Start(PROP_FOLDER[0]);
            //Open PROP in path C and RETURN
            status_label.Text = "  Found it!";
            status_label.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;    
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception) //If PROP cannot be found on any of those paths, the PROP doesn't exist
{

    status_label.Text = " Not Found!";
    status_label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: You ask a question but don't read the comments obviously. Sad. Don't make your code throw excetions! Use the static methods Directory.Exists() and File.Exists. If they return false don't strart the process. This is so simple.